# Synchronize SQL Server table and Postgres table

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql

There is SQL Server database table which is source and Postgres database as destination table. Is there any efficient approach using C# to keep same data on postgres table side reflecting sql server table?

What i tried so far is to use both `System.Data` and `Npgsql`. My idea was to delete every time data in destination table and bulk all data to it from source table. There is nice `SqlBulkCopy` but comming from `System.Data`, i do not see same in `Npgsql`. Could anyone help me out with this?

```
private static void PerformBulkCopy()
        {
            string SourcedestconnectionString = @"";
            string TarettargconnectionString = @"";
            // get the source data
            using (SqlConnection sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(SourcedestconnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [pub].[vw_Services_NDPEWork]", sourceConnection);
                sourceConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                // open the destination data
                using (NpgsqlConnection destinationConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(TarettargconnectionString))
                {
                    // open the connection
                    destinationConnection.Open();

                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 500;
                        bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 1000;
                        bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(Target);
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "roberttest";
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The only thing *close* to `SqlBulkCopy` in `PostgreSQL` is the [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command.

Comment: Why is it mandatory to have a middleware in C# for this job? I think you can do it with a foreign data wrapper on pg side + a daily job. (link for SQLServer fdw : https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ could you show as an answer how could i implement this copy command in my code? I will mark as answer. Keep in mind data is in reader as shown in code and my application will be not on same server as postgres db. I do not see any attribute to say path of csv.. just stdn

Comment: @Henry i am also in the same scenario where i need to sync data from sql view to postgresql table. Could you share me if you found the way to achieve it.